# How to close previous jInternalFrame when open new jInternalFrame in the jDesktopPane

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I created `MDI` (Multiple Document interface) in `java` using `netbeans` in which i have two jbuttons and one jdesktoppane so when clicked on both button then both jinternalframes are opened in same jdesktoppane so i want how to `close previous jinternalframe` when `open new jinternalframe` in the `jdesktoppane` ?

Check snapshot for more better understand my question what i want...
[image]

**First jButton code:**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      try
      {

       tst t = new tst();
        JInternalFrame internalFrame1 = new JInternalFrame("Test Window1"); 
        internalFrame1.add(t.getContentPane());
        internalFrame1.pack();

        internalFrame1.setVisible(true);
        q.add(internalFrame1);

        internalFrame1.setClosable(true);  

        BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI)internalFrame1.getUI();
        Container north = (Container)ui.getNorthPane();
        north.remove(0);
        north.validate();
        north.repaint();

        for(MouseListener listener : ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) internalFrame1.getUI()).getNorthPane().getMouseListeners()){
        ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) internalFrame1.getUI()).getNorthPane().removeMouseListener(listener);
        }

         internalFrame1.setSelected(true);

      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
      }
    }
```

**Second button Code:**

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try
        {

        zxy z = new zxy();
        JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Test Window2"); 
        internalFrame.add(z.getContentPane());
        internalFrame.pack();
        internalFrame.setSize(570,420);

        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
        q.add(internalFrame);

        internalFrame.setClosable(true);  

        BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI)internalFrame.getUI();
        Container north = (Container)ui.getNorthPane();
        north.remove(0);
        north.validate();
        north.repaint();

        for(MouseListener listener : ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) internalFrame.getUI()).getNorthPane().getMouseListeners()){
        ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) internalFrame.getUI()).getNorthPane().removeMouseListener(listener);
        }

         internalFrame.setSelected(true);

        }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call `dispose()` on `JInternalFrame` instance.

To do this you will need to move your `JInternalFrame` declaration out of the method so that we may check if the instance is not `null` (thus there is an existing instance and than call `dispose()` on the instance before creating a new one:

```
JInternalFrame internalFrame1;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      try
      {

       if(internalFrame1 !=null) {//make sure its not null
           internalFrame1.dispose();//close the previos internalframe
       }

        tst t = new tst();
        internalFrame1 = new JInternalFrame("Test Window1"); //create new instance of internal frame
        internalFrame1.add(t.getContentPane());
        internalFrame1.pack();

        internalFrame1.setVisible(true);
        q.add(internalFrame1);

        internalFrame1.setClosable(true);  

        BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI)internalFrame1.getUI();
        Container north = (Container)ui.getNorthPane();
        north.remove(0);
        north.validate();
        north.repaint();

        for(MouseListener listener : ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) internalFrame1.getUI()).getNorthPane().getMouseListeners()){
        ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) internalFrame1.getUI()).getNorthPane().removeMouseListener(listener);
        }

         internalFrame1.setSelected(true);

      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for help and its not working with me may be i make mistake....i add simple dispose(); in JInternalFrame and the above code for jInternaleframe1 after that when press button 2 its close whole application and for button 1 also not working code...

Comment: @AyazAli Im not sure please post an SSCCE but remember we only want to call dispose on the JInternalFrame instance and nothing else. Does copying and pasting my code for the one button work?

Comment: thanks for reply...i found my mistake and now code is working for me and this code is working for same jinternaleframe disposing only......now can you little more help me i need so that is, if jinternalframe 1 is open then i am going to open jinternalframe 2 so the jinternalfamre 1 is automatically close and only jinternalframe 2 open in jdesktopane...

Comment: @AyazAli You'd do the same for the other button as this button and than in  jinternalframe1 create button simply add call like in above code to dispose of  jinternalframe1

Comment: i did in both buttons after that the jinternalframe 1 and jinternalframe 2 repeat opening is stopped but when i clicked button 1 its open jinternalframe 1 and when i clicked button 2 its open jinternalframe 2 so the both ijinternalframes are open going to open in desktoppane and i want when i clicked one button 1 that open its open jinternalframe 1 and when i clicked on button 2 so its open jinternalframe 2 then auto close the jinternalframe 1...so how to do this ?

Comment: @AyazAli close jinternalFrame1 in the method which creates jinternalFrame2. I cant help any further without a SSCCE as we are misunderstanding 1 another

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

Add this to your JButton's event:

```js
JDesktopPane.removeAll();
JDesktopPane.updateUI();

//then add the JInternalFrame into the JDesktopPane
```

I know, I know, this question was 2 years ago, but hope this helps someone else :)